# Probability to be less the expectation

Tags: probability

Let $D$ be a positive random variable with $\mathrm{E}[D] < \infty$. Assume that there exist $y>0$ and $\epsilon>0$ such that: $P(D > \mathrm{E}[D]+y) > \epsilon$. Prove that there exist other $y'>0$, $\epsilon'>0$ such that: $P(D < \mathrm{E}[D]-y') > \epsilon'$.

In words, if there is some probability to be strictly above the expectation then there should be some probability to be strictly below the expectation.

I do not want to assume $V(D)$ is finite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a positive random variable $D$, 
$$E[D] = \int_0^\infty P\{D > x\}\,\mathrm dx$$
where $E[D] = \mu$ is finite by assumption.  We are told that the integrand is positive
at $x = \mu + y$ for some $y > 0$.  Now, the integrand is bounded above by
$1$ and is a decreasing function of $x$.  We have
$$\mu = \int_0^\mu P\{D > x\}\,\mathrm dx + \int_\mu^\infty P\{D > x\}\,\mathrm dx$$
where the second integral has positive value no smaller than $y\cdot P\{D > \mu+y\}$, 
and so 
$$\int_0^\mu P\{D > x\}\,\mathrm dx < \mu.$$ Thus, it is not possible to
have $P\{D > x\} = 1$ for all $x \in [0,\mu]$; it must be that $P\{D > \mu-y^\prime\} < 1$
for some $y^\prime > 0$.  In words, if there is probability
mass to the right of $\mu$, then there must be probability mass to the left of $\mu$.